# Can email be hosted by a different company when the domain is registered with GoDaddy, and the site is hosted with Wix?

Tags: dns, email, mx

I registered a domain name with GoDaddy and I changed the DNS to point to my site on wix.com (my host).

I don't have email with GoDaddy or Wix, but I have a hosting account with RS Hosting (cPanel). How can I setup an email account with RS Hosting when the domain is registered with GoDaddy while keeping the web hosting at Wix?

Answer (score 4):

To have your email hosted with a different company, you simply need to set your `MX` records in your DNS.  [Here is an in depth article](http://help.dnsmadeeasy.com/spry_menu/mx-record/) with lots of information about how to do that.

The basics are:

1. Your mail host gives you the names of your mail servers
2. You create `MX` records with in DNS with those host names (and a priority)

The MX records can point somewhere completely different from the main A or CNAME records that are used for your web server.